# Will all 4 cores work if the PSU has 4-pin supply instead of EPS12V?

Tags: cpu, power-supply, connector, atx

Motherboard: P7P55D-E PRO

Processor  : i5-760

PSU        : Gigabyte Superb 460

The PSU provides a 4-pin CPU connector; whereas the m/b has an 8-pin socket (2 sockets are covered/protected by a rubber flap)

My question is - Will all 4 cores work with this 4-pin connector, or is an EPS12V compatible connector necessary?

EDIT: After the post the related area showed this [Is using 4-pin connector for 8-pin ATX 12V power connector ok?](https://superuser.com/questions/145843/is-using-4-pin-connector-for-8-pin-atx-12v-power-connector-ok) that almost covers this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary, the 8-pin was originally used for dual CPU motherboard designs.

But seeing as the older CPU's Intel P4 and PD's ran just fine with a 4-pin, I don't see why today's CPU's shouldn't, since they have much less power.

The 8-pin just provides extra juice to the CPU, depending on the circuitry of the board.

I have the 8-pin connected on my motherboard and can't really tell the difference between it and using the 4-pin. The only reason I done it was that my PSU (Be Quiet Dark Power Pro) came with an 8Pin lead that I could plug in and thought I might as well.